# Does the singular cohomology theory agree with Alexander-Spanier's for compact metric spaces?

Tags: algebraic-topology

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander%E2%80%93Spanier_cohomology, we know that
the Alexander–Spanier cohomology groups coincide with Cech's for compact metric spaces, and coincide with singular cohomology groups for locally finite complexes.

From the link above, I can not get the relation of AS and singular cohomology for general compact metric spaces. Whether someone can said something about it?

Comment: AS/Cech do not coincide with singular, which actually is a well known fact. Consider $\ \{0\}\times[-1;1]\cup\{(x\ \sin(\frac 1x)):0<x\le 1\}\subseteq\mathbb R^2.\ $ This space is acyclic w.r. to AS/Cech but singularly it has $\ H^0=\mathbb Z^2$ since there are 2 path components. This space is acyclic in the first sense because it is an inverse limit of closed intervals.

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński Thank you for your example! I got it.